# Partially constructed object

Tags: java

Is this possible if an object is visible to other threads during its initialization (visible while doing initialization but not completed yet)? If yes then could you please give a simple example to backup your justification?

Comment: I guess it is Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681881/when-does-a-java-object-become-non-null-during-construction

Answer (score 5):

This can happen in a number of ways.

- You pass your object to another thread in the constructor, e.g. you start a thread in your constructor.
- You pass the object to another thread but the other thread sees old, uninitialized values because the fields are not final or volatile or accessed in a locked or synchronized block.  Other fields are not guarenteed to be thread safe.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I have question about volatile variable like: volatile Pool pool = new Pool(); where is pool pointing to now if Pool constructor throws exception in the middle of initialization'

Comment: @FinalIllusion If the Pool constructor throws an exception, the Pool reference will be unchanged -- it won't refer to a partially-constructed object.

Comment: @yshavit you mean that it's still pointing to previous assigned instance?

Comment: Yes, exactly -- or to null, if the reference was previously null.

Comment: If you pass the `this` in the constructor somewhere and throw an Exception, you will have a partially constructed object. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The best case in point would be the notoriously broken double-checked locking idiom. I'll extract from it only the part relevant for this argument. Take this code:

```
public class Holder { public static File f; }
```

Somewhere in Thread A you do `Holder.f = new File("path");` and elsewhere in Thread B you do `File xxf = Holder.f;` and proceed to use it. There is no guarantee that, even if you read the reference to `Holder.f`, any field of the `File` instance will be in any defined state. You may read all nulls, (zeros, falses, depending on type), as well as any combination of non-null and null values.

Comment: If an object's constructor sets a `final` field to refer to a newly-constructed and newly-written holder which has never been exposed via any other means; would the storage of the reference to a `final` field guarantee that all writes to items within the object have completed?

Comment: Quoting JLS 17.5: "when the object is seen by another thread, that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's `final` fields. It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those `final` fields that are at least as up-to-date as the `final` fields are." I think this covers exactly what you asked about.

Comment: Thanks.  So if an object is created for the sole purpose of having a reference to it placed into a final field, and if it will never be exposed to anything that will modify it after that, the object itself doesn't need to worry about whether any of its fields are `final`.  Very useful to know.  Thanks.